# Conventions of Importing Python Main Programs

Tags: python

Often I write command line utilities that are only meant to be run as main. For example, I might have a file that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    # do stuff
```

In other words, there is nothing going on that isn't under the if statement checking that this file is being run as main. I tried importing a file like this to see what would happen, and the import was successful.

So as I expected, one is allowed to import files like this, but what is the convention surrounding this practice? Is one supposed to throw an error telling the user that there is nothing to be imported? Or if all the contents of the file are supposed to be run as main, does one need to check if the program is being run as main? Or is the conditional not necessary?

Also, if I have import statements, should they be at the top of the file, or under the conditional? If the modules are only being used under the conditional, it would seem to me that they should be imported under the conditional and not at the top of the file.

Comment: It's bad practice to have your entire module under main, and most likely if you do, either you have an extremely simple program, or are violating [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Make more use of functions and have the code under the conditional primarily run the code in your functions.

Comment: This is a good point. I'm sure if I look I will find instances of violating DRY, but it is mostly the former, as these scripts are very simple. But this is also quite rare for me. Usually, there is something to stick outside of main.

Answer (score 4):

If you are writing simple utilities that you are entirely certain that you will never import as a module in another program, then you really do not need to include the `if __name__ == '__main__'` stuff.  The fundamental point of that construct is to allow a module to be developed that can both be imported as a module for use, and run as a stand-alone program for some other purpose.  For example, if you had a module and had some test vectors you wanted to run on it regularly, you would put the trigger mechanism for your test vectors in the `if __name__` block.

Another example might be if you have a stand-alone program that you develop, that would also provide useful functions for others.  If you have a look at the pip module, this is an excellent example of this technique.

Comment: "you will never import as a module in another program" -- not even for example by a documentation generator/server.

Comment: Never, my grandmother used to say, is a very long time.  I agree whole-heartedly with your sentiment here.  Having said that, I have literally dozens of ten-liners that do very specific things and none of them have the `if __name__` construct.  They will never go through a document generator, etc.

So yeah - best practice - always use the `if __name__` construct.  Realistically you can do without in highly specific circumstances (about which the original poster seemed to be asking).